# Как реализовать обрезку фотографии с выбором места на фотографии?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, vue.js, asp.net-core

Я хочу, как в соц. сетях, сделать обрезку фотографии и выбора аватарки.
Тоесть пользователь выбирает фото, наводит на области, затем фотография загружается и сервер обрезает фото, делая уменьшённую фотографию,скажем 50*50 px и чуть побольше-100*100 из той области, что указал пользователь.
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос. Вам нужно написать UI для выбора области обрезки, отправить эту область на сервер, и там отрезать кусок от картинки какой-нибудь из подходящих функций.